# Cell background color cannot be set to nil for search result

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, default, background-color

I've a tableview with default background color headers. I also have a filter bar, that filters the table results. When filtering, the headers become all black bars.

If I set the background color to some specific color in viewForHeaderInSection there is no unexpected behavior. If I set backgroundColor to nil it works as expected, giving default color, but not when I search.

Is somehow the default cell background color for a search results black?

**Here is some code from my experiments:**

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HeaderCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    //cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.663 green:0.663 blue:0.663 alpha:1];
    //[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:nil];
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    }
    [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [[cell textLabel] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}
```

The code above will show default headers normally and lightGray after searching. If I put the [cell setBackgroundColor:nil]; in the if statement I get the black bars.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Also, if there is no elegant fix, can anyone tell me what the default background color is so I can manually set it?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you setting the default background colors of your headers?

Comment: [cell setBackgroundColor:nil] between the if statements. In the code above I'm showing how it can be made to work, sorta, without a default color in searches. If I remove the if statement below the line I mentioned, then I get the black bar behavior in search results.

Comment: What happens if you remove this lines  `[cell setBackgroundColor:nil];
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    }`.  I mean why are you setting the background to nil on this method?. I can guess that you are assigning background colors on Interface Builder for this cell; but on this code, you are calling just one custom cell : _"HeaderCell"_ so all your headers have the same background color? Why not applying it here by code too

Comment: In the case you have multiple background colors, then you should be using more than just one custom cell on your Interface Builder. OR you could be assigning the background color by code according to its section, but this logic should be present on your method `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` as well

Comment: Not applying it at all results in the black bar behavior. It's the same as always setting backgroundcolor = nil. I set it explicitly because I thought maybe the search result was pulling a backgroundcolor from somewhere else or something.

Answer (score 1):

Well of course it will go black if you set the background color to `nil`. Your are effectively getting rid of the `UIColor` object that the cell uses to sets its back-color.

You have to set the color back to what it was before. I see you have the color code above, but you have it commented. Is it not working for you?

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.663 green:0.663 blue:0.663 alpha:1];
```

Comment: No... that's a custom color I used to use. And nil works for default if it's not a search.